# How to apply multiple transforms to the same columns using ColumnTransformer in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'x' : range(0,5),
    'y' : [1,2,3,np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

[image]

I want to impute the values for y and also apply standardization to the two variables with the following code:

```
columnPreprocess = ColumnTransformer([
('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median'), ['x','y']),   
('scaler', StandardScaler(), ['x','y'])])
columnPreprocess.fit_transform(df)
```

However, it seems like the `ColumnTransformer` would setup separate columns for each steps, with different transformations in different columns. This is not what I intended.

[image]

Is there a way to apply different transformation to the same columns and result in the same number of columns in the outputting array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) in this case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(0, 5),
    'y': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan]
})

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

pipeline.fit_transform(df)
# array([[-1.41421356, -1.58113883],
#        [-0.70710678,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  1.58113883],
#        [ 0.70710678,  0.        ],
#        [ 1.41421356,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: can you please provide your thoughts on what should I be doing, if I want to do there are only some common columns between the transformations ? I.e, I want to apply.
For my usecase, I wanted to perform target encoding for some columns (say c1, c2,c3) and I also want to perform imputation for a column (c4) and I now wanted to perform standardscalar (once the previous target encoding and imputation are performed) for all these and more columns (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8).

Note I also have more columns that I need to perform, say OHE, but those columns are disjoint from the above c1...c8.