# How can I apply multiple transforms to the same columns with ColumnTransformer in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a heterogenous dataframe that looks as follows (**Note**: the dataset being used is one from Kaggle - [IEE Fraud Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ieee-fraud-detection/data):

[image: Example df]

I have used `ColumnTransformer` to implement multiple transformations:

```
# merging transformations into one pipeline with columntransformer
process_pipe = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        (
            "most_frequent_imputer", 
            PandasSimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), 
            impute_freq
        ), 
        (
            "aggregate_high_cardinality_features",
            AggregateCategorical(high_cardinality_cats),
            high_cardinality_cats
        ), 
        (
            "get_categorical_codes",
            FunctionTransformer(convert_to_category),
            cat_codes_cols
        ),
        (
            "mean_imputer",
            PandasSimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),
            continuous_features
        )
    ],
    remainder="passthrough",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False
)
```

**Note**: `PandasSimpleImputer` is a wrapper class I created to return a pandas dataframe from sklearn `SimpleImputer`. `AggregateCategorical` is a class I created to reduce the cardinality of a high dimensional feature.

However, the `ColumnTransformer` creates new columns for each step with the name of the transformation prefixed at the front. But, I've got features that I perform multiple transformations on in different steps of the pipeline - meaning after one transformation happens to my feature, I want another transformation to happen to the feature only after the first transformation (i.e. impute missing values --> get category codes).

At the moment, my pipeline imputes the missing values then references the original feature (not the imputed one) and get the codes from that feature. This is not the functionality I want.

The most straightforward solution I could think of is to name the features with multiple features with the prefix so that the transformations happen to the same features, then delete the features I do not want from the dataframe. This solution includes lots of manual labor. Is there a faster way?

Similar question but different scenario -> [How to apply multiple transforms to the same columns using ColumnTransformer in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783780/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-to-the-same-columns-using-columntransformer-in)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you want to perform multiple stacked transformations on a columns but at the moment you only get multiple outputs for that column, one where each transform is applied individually.

To get the behaviour you want, I think you need to write pipelines for each combination of transformations you want, just like the accepted answer in the similar question you linked to. Your column transformer will then consist of multiple pipelines, one for each combination of transforms you want to apply.

This is a perfectly acceptable solution but you can quickly end up with a lot of code to maintain. Because I kept hitting on this problem, I wrote a package called `skdag` to try to make this sort of task simpler. You can read the full documentation at https://skdag.readthedocs.io/ but here's a quick demo based on your question:

```
from skdag import DAGBuilder
dag = (
    DAGBuilder(infer_dataframe=True)
    .add_step("input", "passthrough")
    .add_step(
        "cat_imputer",
        SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
        deps={"input": ["C1", "C2", "C3"]}
    )
    .add_step(
        "get_categorical_codes",
        FunctionTransformer(convert_to_category),
        deps={"cat_imputer": ["C1", "C2", "C3"], "input": ["C4"]}
    )
    .add_step(
        "mean_imputer",
        SimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),
        deps={"input": ["N1", "N2", "N3", "N4"]}
    )
    .add_step(
        "pca",
        PCA(n_components=2),
        deps=["mean_imputer"]
    )
    .add_step(
        "numerics",
        "passthrough",
        deps={"pca": ["pca1", "pca2"], "input": ["N5", "N6"]}
    )
    .add_step(
        "output",
        "passthrough",
        deps=["get_categorical_codes", "numerics"]
    )
    .make_dag()
)

dag.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Note that there's no need for any custom dataframe wrappers any more. `skdag` deals with it all natively for you if you set the `infer_dataframe` option.

You could also add a predictor (or multiple predictors) to the end of the graph and then call `fit_predict` instead if you like.

This is quite a big, complex workflow now so it may become hard to keep track of from looking at the code alone. If you want to visualise the graph, you can call dag.show() in an interactive environment like Jupyter Notebooks, or dag.draw() to produce an image or text file:

```
dag.show()
```

[image: dag]

This hopefully makes it easier to understand the workflow. We have four categorical features, three of which are run through an most frequent imputer first and then all of them go through the function transformer to convert them to codes. We have four numerical features which are mean imputed and then run through PCA, and two more numerical features that are just passed through without any modification.